# JS method parseFloat does not return correct value

Tags: javascript, floating-point, parsefloat

```
parseFloat("-999999999999999.9991") returns -1000000000000000
```

and when debuging

`(-1000000000000000 == -999999999999999.999)` condition is true.

Answer (score 4):

Operations with float data type have limited precision and they often introduce errors when rounding numbers like your case.

Comment: how to make it return true like parseFloat("-999999999999999.9991") < -999999999999999.999

Comment: Well, in other programming languages you can use the decimal data type. In javascript there is no such data type, though and the solution is a little bit trickier. You can check the following links for a workaround of this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem or http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic2.html. In general you should round your number to 2 or 3 signs after the decimal point before involving them in any operation.